# Is it possible to have street names / roads on top of an image overlay in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to insert the [image overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay) a layer below the streets but on top of the map background? The roads can be individually styled, so it should technically work, but I haven't been able to find the option for it.

The only lead I have found so far is this question:  [Google Maps API - Overlay Custom Roads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017762/google-maps-api-overlay-custom-roads)
Which unfortunately doesn't really solve the problem of having to manually enter the street info.

I'm currently working on a custom map for a whole city and manually illustrate all the streets and enter the street names would take an enormous amount of time.

Any info would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) about Styled Maps. Styled maps allow you to customize the presentation of the standard Google base maps, changing the visual display of such elements as roads, parks, and built-up areas.

Here you can also find some sample code that you can use in your sample code.

Also you can find here the [Styled Map Wizard](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Creating styles by hand and testing your code to see how they look is potentially time-consuming. Instead, you can use the Styled Map Wizard to set up the JSON for your map's styles. The wizard allows you to select features and their elements, apply operations to those features, and save the styles to JSON, which you can copy and paste into your application.